# Как создать сводную таблицу из JSON, полученную при парсинге сайта?

Tags: python, json, requests

Имеется ресурс, с которого выполняется запрос:

```
import requests
url_home = 'https://nsddata.ru/api/get/companies?limit=10&product=2&exclude=code_nsd,name_full,name_full_en,name_short_en,name_full_tr,name_short_tr,name_short_hde,inn,company_type,cmp_code_fcsm,kpp,credit_cmp,is_bank_4_non_resident,okpo,bik,state_reg_num,state_reg_date,state_reg_authority,ogrn,egrul_date,egrul_authority,country,market,fio_head,position_head,address,address_en,post_address,phone,fax,e_mail,www,lei_code,lei_assignment_date,lei_verification_date,okved,tin,tax_number,licenses,is_resident,register_custody,pif_type,state,okato,securities.id,securities.isin,securities.code_nsd,securities.name_full_en,securities.instr_type,securities.state_reg_number,securities.cfi,securities.form,securities.type_br,securities.for_qualified_investors,securities.for_qualified_investors_date_from,securities.listing,securities.storages,securities.storages_tier2,securities.nsd_date_from,securities.nsd_date_to,securities.state_reg_date,securities.state_reg_authority,securities.state,securities.facial_account,securities.notes,securities.share.custody_type,securities.share.category,securities.share.type,securities.share.currency,securities.share.registrar,securities.share.placement_type,securities.share.origin_issued_size,securities.share.issue_number,securities.share.rp_reg_date,securities.share.rp_state,securities.share.rp_reg_authority,securities.share.start_placement_date,securities.share.end_placement_date,securities.share.is_in_pawnshop_list,securities.share.conditions,securities.share.is_fractional,securities.share.fraction,securities.share.circulation_type,securities.share.mls,securities.share._at,securities.share._at2,securities.bond,securities.unit,securities.dep_receipt,securities.mortgage_certificate,securities.clearing_certificate,securities.corp_actions,securities.add_info,securities.record_method,securities.no_transfers_within_nsd,securities.no_transfers_to_nsd,securities.proh_recept_stor,securities.proh_trans_tax,securities.constraint_reasons,securities.name,securities._p,securities._at,securities._at2,cbr,_p,_at,_at2&apikey=DEMO'
r = requests.get(url_home)
r.json()
```

JSON в виде сложного словаря получен.

Но как обратиться к конкретным полям, типа `id, name_short, auth_capital`, а также создать производные поля `sum(face_value * issue_size_planned), sum(face_value * issue_size)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь уже знакомым вам модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r.json(), ['securities'])
d2 = d1.pop('share').apply(pd.Series)
tmp = d.join(d2.drop(0,axis=1))

formulas="""
val_issued = face_value * issued_size
val_planned = face_value * issue_size_planned
"""

res = tmp.eval(formulas).groupby('name_full', as_index=False)[['val_issued','val_planned']].sum()
```

Результат:

```
In [70]: res.sort_values('val_issued')
Out[70]:
                                             name_full    val_issued   val_planned
0                                       "КСУ GC Bonds"  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
147  Биржевые облигации документарные процентные не...  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
148  Биржевые облигации документарные процентные не...  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
149  Биржевые облигации документарные процентные не...  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
150  Глобальная депозитарная расписка  на обыкновен...  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
..                                                 ...           ...           ...
16            Акции обыкновенные АО "БЕЛЭЛЕКТРОКАБЕЛЬ"  4.328200e+07  2.732940e+08
19               Акции обыкновенные АО "Салаватстекло"  4.976829e+07  1.350726e+07
20   Акции обыкновенные АО "Салаватстекло" (дробная...  4.976829e+07  1.350726e+07
13                 Bank of America Corporation_ORD SHS  1.008515e+08  1.280000e+08
15   Акции обыкновенные "Азиатско-Тихоокеанский Бан...  1.283585e+09  1.275483e+09

[233 rows x 3 columns]
```